# The plot method plots the list shifted back by one, while scatter is ok

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter

Hi the following code represents the first 10 integers' cubes.
The scatter method works fine, the plot method shifts everything one to the left.
The axis looks correct to me.

I tried to figure it out but I don't know where I'm going wrong.
Thank you .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_values = range(1,11,1)
n_cubes = [n**3 for n in n_values]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(n_cubes)
ax.scatter(n_values, n_cubes, c=n_cubes, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, s=20)
ax.axis([1, 12, 0, 1100])

print(n_cubes, n_values)

plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `ax.plot()` with only one argument, it will make its own x-axis values. In python, these start with zero. So, all is shifted.
So, you need to call the function like this:

```
ax.plot(n_values, n_cubes)
```